# How to optimize filter on ng-repeat with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Today I wanted to know How can I optimize the rapidity of execution of my filter.

My object that I ng-repeat to append a list can have a length of 1000 or 10000 but it begin to RAM when I got only a length of 100...

If anyone has a trick I wish accept it with pleasure ! thx !

Comment: It's difficult to help without more specific information. But have you considered some kind of pagination?

Comment: What does the filter do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
<input ng-model='filterby' />
<div ng-repeat='book in books|filter:filterby|limitTo:50' ng-show='filterby'>
```

Comment: it's interresting thx.
but why the ng-show ?

Comment: ng-show will be helpful for showing the data when the search is active(means when we entered something in search box). otherwise it will be in hide state. Can you accept the answer, so that someone can find it out as a correct  answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know. In fact the filter attribute is set in the ng-repeat attribute and linked to an input.
In my case with an input text. For example when A user type a text in this input it will foreach my object and append my element in function of the length of the new object returned by the filter.
So if you have a list appended by a ng-repeat and so you have 1000

{{object.infos}}

and you type in your input 'test', the filter search if 'test' match in {{object.infos}} if yes it returned all the matched object and reappend for example if I had a returned object with a length of 500, 500

{{object.infos}}

. so it removed and append any element everytime your type something in your input text. so its really hardcore for your browser...

```
<div ng-repeat="test in tests | filter:search"></div>
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />

appController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.tests = {0:{infos...},1:{infos:...},...,1000:{infos...}}
}
```